# Choosing between response codes when redirecting with React-Router

Tags: redirect, react-router

In a React-based application with server-side rendering, I am using the `match` [utility](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#match-routes-location-history-options--cb) of React Router. To redirect from some urls to others, I use React Router's `Redirect` component. On the server side, I am checking the `redirect` parameter of the callback function that `match` takes (which is the `Location` object), and if this parameter is present (as it is when the `Redirect` component is matched), I use it for redirecting, like so:

```
  if (redirect) {
    let { pathname, search } = redirect;

    res.redirect(301, `${pathname}${search}`);
  }
```

Here is the problem. In the code snippet above, my server will always redirect with http code 301, while I need to send 302 responses in some cases, and 301's in others. I can't figure out a good, idiomatic way to pass an extra piece of information through React Router, which the server can then use to decide between a 301 or a 302 redirect. Could you please offer any suggestions?

Comment: I am trying to solve the exact same problem. Right now I'm thinking I will default to `301` and add `302` status code to `state` in the replace location descriptor.

Comment: Yep, eventually I did the same exact thing :-)